# Team explorer builds error - Stream does not support reading

Tags: build, tfs, team-explorer

When i open the builds tab in team explorer i get an error "Stream does not support reading" and the builds and build definitions don't show up.

Things already tried:

- Clearing TFS Cache
- Restarting (entire computer)
- Clearing TFS Cache + Restarting (entire computer)

Has anyone had this issue before?
Note that other teammembers are having no issues. only 2 out of 10..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the stream is closed before the read is done, I think that your server IIS crash when you try to read your datas, so i suggest you to `check your IIS.`

Web services of your Tem Explorer are hosted on your IIS server.