# Stream does not support reading. TFS 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs, tfs-2015, tfs-workitem

Since few days now, I'm having this TFS error "Stream does not support reading." when trying to open my work items on Visual studio 2015. I tried all possible solutions (clearing cache, restart computer and so on, nothing works). When I open my work items on TFS web portail, it's all fine.

The error is only on my Visual Studio 2015 Team explorer (I can connect to the team explorer successfully, but no work items)

[image]

I saw that this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19951718/team-explorer-builds-error-stream-does-not-support-reading) discusses the same issue, but I don't get the answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was finally found. I needed to disable my anti-virus and clear all the temp files (my disk was almost full). Now everything works fine.